# PHP RewriteRule detect if url contain “string” & replace, & drop sequence after .php?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We recently completely redesigned our website and moved to a different CMS system. I'm trying to set up redirects based on the old web structure to direct everything to our new site by recognizing a string in any of hundreds of possible urls. For the purposes of this post, I'm focused on the string "_xdc.php".

**Example:** I want `http://www.mysite.com/_xdc.php?somerandomstring` to rewrite (301) to `http://www.mysite.com`.

Currently I am using this:
`RewriteRule ^.*xdc.*$ http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L]`

This method works in so far as it does redirect to the site homepage. There are two problems though.

1. **1st problem:** the gibberish after the ? is appending and I don't want it to.
   Basically: `http://www.mysite.com/_xdc.php?somerandomstring` becomes `http://www.mysite.com/?somerandomstring` but I want it to be ONLY `http://www.mysite.com`
2. **2nd Problem:** If i ever create a new page that includes the  letters "xdc" it will be redirected. However when i tried limiting to `^.*_xdc.php*` the rewrite did not work at all. I'm sure this has something to do with the _ and . in "_xdc.php", but I'm not sure how to forcing reading those special characters as plain text and not code...

What am I missing? I'm sure its something obvious, but i'm still a noob at htaccess, so i'd greatly appreciate your help!

In case its needed, I've include my full htaccess below:

```
RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.

# redirect any variations of a specific character string to a specific address
RewriteRule ^calendar http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^.*xdc.*$ http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L]

#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

RewriteBase /deloro

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]


ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem can be fixed by appending a `?` to the rewritten url *or* by using the QSD (query string discard) flag ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd); available from Apache 2.4.0 and up).

```
RewriteRule ^.*xdc.*$ http://www.mysite.com? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^.*xdc.*$ http://www.mysite.com [R=301,L,QSD]
```

---

For the second problem, if you want `http://www.mysite.com/_xdc.php` to match (and only that url), you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^_xdc\.php$ http://www.mysite.com [R]
```

Your current attempt (`^.*xdc.*$` is pretty much the same as matching `xdc`). I am not aware of any special meaning of the `_` character, but if you need to escape a character, you have to prepend a `\` (e.g. `\.` will match a literal dot, instead of 'every character'). Above rule works fine for me. See also [the documentation for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and [some basic information about htaccess regex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex).

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate both the assistance and the reference docs

Comment: Interestingly, on question 1 adding ? worked perfectly, but trying to instead use QSD rendered an internal server error. No clue why, but since ? works, that's the route I'm using

Comment: QSD is only available from Apache 2.4.0 and up. I've added that information to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm learning as I go and every bit helps.